# iOS 9+ Push notification with text input doesn't call handleActionWithIdentifier: forRemoteNotification: withResponseInfo:

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications

In short:
I can add custom input text boxes to respond to a push notification. I just can't get the associated app delegate to fire to actually handle the input from the user.

I have two custom actions, say `acceptAction` (a simple actionable action) and `replyAction` (one with `UIUserNotificationActionBehaviorTextInput` behavior) added to a custom `UIMutableUserNotificationCategory` and added this category to  my `UIUserNotificationSettings`. All notifications are fired properly. All buttons show up as `UIUserNotificationTypeAlert`.

While the `acceptAction` fires the

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo withResponseInfo:(NSDictionary *)responseInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
```

and I can't get the `replyAction` to fire the same. I can see a text box, can enter data, can press send, but no effect after that. I actually want to capture that input text with the `UIUserNotificationActionResponseTypedTextKey`.

What am I missing?

Extra info: Though I have no idea why, if I also implement the basic

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

along with the other method, I can see that the `replyAction` fires this and not the other, while the `acceptAction` fires only the first method.

I also have background modes setup properly in my app properly.

Comment: did u get text from textfield?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the following method instead.
 `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification withResponseInfo:(NSDictionary *)responseInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler`

The `responseInfo` dictionary contains the `UIUserNotificationActionResponseTypedTextKey` key with the text response entered by the user.